# Uploading file to FTP server in a particular folder location

Tags: batch-file, file-upload, ftp

I am uploading a file to a remote server (Ex. 123.45.678.90) using batch file and the log shows successfully transferred the file.

Whereas in that server (123.45.678.90) I am unable to locate that file.
Please suggest how do I transfer the file to a particular folder in the server [`D:\SuccessTransaction`].

```
@echo off
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 20 -w 60000 > nul

del ftpcmd.dat

echo user myuser>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mypassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo BINARY>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put D:\Files\Success*.csv>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 123.45.678.90 >> FileUploadLog.txt
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `Success*.csv` uploads a single file only, not all files matching the mask?

Comment: Yes, it uploads a single file. The use of asterisk is because after Success, today's date is appended to filename. One single file is placed in D:\Files\ everyday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `put` command takes optional second argument, where you specify a target path.

Though you have to know the FTP path. You cannot use the local Windows path (local as of the server).

So if, for example, the `D:\` is the FTP root, the FTP path of the `D:\SuccessTransaction` will be like `/SuccessTransaction`.

Then the `put` command will be like:

```
put D:\Files\Success*.csv /SuccessTransaction/Success.csv
```

---

If you want to keep the changing source name, you need to use `cd` and `mput`:

```
cd /SuccessTransaction
mput D:\Files\Success*.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I am able to upload the file to the desired folder location in server.